# Touch screen type

Tags: identification, touchscreen, touch-panel

[image: Touch Screen]

I know there are many different types of touch screen out there. In the attached picture, could someone tell me what type of touch screen that is? I am looking to buy some screens like this one for a project but don't know what I should be looking for.

Comment: This is very difficult to tell, based on a picture. There are various touch screen technologies (capacitive, resistive, etc...) and the screen below may be of various kind.
A better option would be to describe what your requirements are. But remember that question about shopping are out of scope here. Thus act wisely..

Answer (score 3):

Most probably this is a resistive touchscreen, as one would expect in a non-consumer appliance.

Looking at [service manual](http://www.merrychef.com/us/products/cook-ovens/accelerated-cooking/electric/eikon-e4), on page 29 they suggest a non-abrasive pointer for calibration. Since no additional material requirements are given, it is clearly not capacitive or SAW.

Resistive touchscreens are quite easy to use with an ordinary MCU, and it only takes 4(in most cases) GPIO/ADC pins. In addition, they can be operated with gloves and are immune to splashing water (particularly important in kitchen appliance like this).

Comment: In addition to what venny said, the resistive touch screens are generally soft and deform slightly when you press on them, whereas capacitive touch screens can be as hard as glass (or sapphire).